# Communication links failure in Docker+DockerCompose+MySQL+SpringBoot

Tags: mysql, spring, docker, maven

I'm trying to execute an application in a docker container, the app is compiled by Maven and it need to connect to a MySQL database that is on another container.
I use Spring Boot with a Maven Project to create it.
The app starts with the `docker compose` command and throws the next error:

```
royectodiagrama-app-1      | com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |
proyectodiagrama-app-1      | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
proyectodiagrama-app-1      |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar!/:5.3.22]
```

I use two Dockerfiles:

```
`Dockerfile`:

FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN mvn clean package

COPY *.jar /app/target/ProyectoDiagrama-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app/target/ProyectoDiagrama-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

And `Dockerfile-sql`:

```
FROM mysql:5.7

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=proyectodiagrama

ENV MYSQL_USER=root
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=root

COPY estaciones.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

My `Docker-compose.yml` is:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-sql
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=proyectodiagrama
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  app:
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
        "spring.datasource.url"  : "jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/proyectodiagrama?useSSL=false",
        "spring.datasource.username" : "root",
        "spring.datasource.password" : "root",
        "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect" : "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect",
        "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" : "create"
      }'

    volumes:
      - .m2:/root/.m2

volumes:
  db:
```

And, just in case, this is my project `.properties`:

```
#logging
logging.level.root=info
logging.file.name=application.org

#port
server.port=8095
#server.servlet.context-path=/proyecto
#spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
#spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
#spring.web.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/

#database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/proyectodiagrama     #cambiar a localhost 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root


#crear tablas la primera vez:
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
#debugSql
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

#seguridad
spring.security.user.name=usuario 
spring.security.user.password=pass
```

I have to say that I can connect to database with the Workbench of MySQL, using user root and password root, I don't know if this could be helpful.

Thanks on advance.

Comment: Is it really for sure that the MySQL app is correctly started... because I don't see any health check for MySQL ?

Comment: @khmarbaise yeah it started, it´s only that I only show the Spring error log but above that there is code that proves it started.